# Visual studio error list like toolwindow

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Does anyone knows how to create VSIX plugin with visual studio build error list like toolwindow. It should contain the grid like image1   but when i add a WPF grid view to toolwindow it is not the same grid in visual studio (image 2)

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iqXm.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wRc0.png)

Comment: Use Styles or Templates to change the design if that's what you are talking about.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a custom tool windows with error list message in it?

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT: Yes ColeWu, I need to create a similar window and bind a custom error list to it with filter and sorting behaviors as in the VS Errol list window.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following method to retrieve related errorlist, then add the result to custom tool window.

```
DTE2 dte = (DTE2)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
        ErrorList errList = dte.ToolWindows.ErrorList;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

       int  count = errList.ErrorItems.Count;
        if (count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                list.Add(errList.ErrorItems.Item(i).Description.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Here is a demo about Adding Search to a Tool Window for your reference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266761.aspx